# Javascript sources conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a site that uses javascript for a dropdown search list. The site also has a popover. When I put the source below into the header the dropdown search list does not have a **search** function working, however the popover works, and vis-versa.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
```

Popover

```
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to make the scripts relate to specific source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `$` function collides, use `(jQuery)` instead

Comment: hmm... i don't see any evidence of a conflict in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue; the src had to be higher up in the Header. This page helped me: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)